# Extract country name from text in column to create another column

Tags: python, dataframe, country

I have tried different combinations to extract the country names from a column and create a new column with solely the countries. I can do it for selected rows i.e. df.address[9998] but not for the whole column.

```
import pycountry
Cntr = []
for country in pycountry.countries:
    for country.name in df.address:
        Cntr.append(country.name)
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

**edit:**

address is an object in the df and

df.address[:10]  looks like this

```
       Address
0    Turin, Italy        
1    NaN                 
2    Zurich, Switzerland 
3    NaN                 
4    Glyfada, Greece     
5    Frosinone, Italy    
6    Dublin, Ireland     
7    NaN                 
8    Turin, Italy        
1    NaN                 
2    Zurich, Switzerland 
3    NaN                 
4    Glyfada, Greece     
5    Frosinone, Italy    
6    Dublin, Ireland     
7    NaN                 
8   ...                  
9    Kristiansand, Norway
Name: address, Length: 10, dtype: object
```

Based on Petar's response when I run individual queries I get the country correctly, but when I try to create a column with all the countries (or ranges like df.address[:5] I get an empty Cntr)

```
    import pycountry
    Cntr = []
    for country in pycountry.countries:
        if country.name in df['address'][1]:
            Cntr.append(country.name)
Cntr
Returns
[Italy]

and df.address[2] returns [ ] 
etc.
```

I have also run 
`df['address'] = df['address'].astype('str')`

to make sure that there are no floats or int in the column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your posted code depends upon an undefined data frame, and you haven't demonstrated a problem for us to fix.  Don't forget to trace your program (`print` statements are a good start) to check on data types and contents.

Comment: can you show the `df`, a for loop is almost never the solution, a regex might be better

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. I agree with @Kenan, a loop likely isn't necessary here. Also, I would really recommend using `[ ]` for DataFrame column access, instead of the dot/`.`/attribute style.

Comment: Thank you all ! I will make sure to use proper naming in my code. I have added the first 10 lines of the feature to make in clearer. If there is anything else I can add, please let me know. Also, @Kenan I didn't know how I could make it work with regex. I tried this df['address_new'] = df['address'].astype(str).str.split().str[1], but it did not end up well, so I decided to try pycountry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample dataframe
`df = pd.DataFrame({'address': ['Turin, Italy', np.nan, 'Zurich, Switzerland', np.nan, 'Glyfada, greece']})`

`df[['city', 'country']] = df['address'].str.split(',', expand=True, n=2)`

```
               address     city       country
0         Turin, Italy    Turin         Italy
1                  NaN      NaN           NaN
2  Zurich, Switzerland   Zurich   Switzerland
3                  NaN      NaN           NaN
4      Glyfada, greece  Glyfada        greece
```

Comment: I get this error "Columns must be same length as key". I don't know if it relevant but looking at the first 100 values I can see that I have some instances like this "65    Αθηνα" or this "91    France". I thought that it might somehow be related to "nan" values, so I changed them to "None", but the problem persists. I also checked other related questions to this issue but I haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: OK. I think it works like this
`df[['city', 'country']] = df['address'].str.split(',', expand=True, n=1)` but I guess in this case I lose the countries that are in the format "country" instead of "city, country"

Comment: I don't think you will try it out, you can always `fillna` in the `country` column with `address`

Comment: I finally used this code ''' df[['city', 'or']] = df['Ror'].str.split(',', expand=True, n=1)
df['or'].fillna('NaN', inplace=True) '''

Answer (score 0):

You were really close. We cannot loop like this `for country.name in df.address`. Instead:

```
import pycountry
Cntr = []
for country in pycountry.countries:
    if country.name in df.address:
        Cntr.append(country.name)
```

If this does not work, please supply more information because I am unsure what `df.address` looks like.

Comment: Thank you Petar! I have edited the question based on your response. Unfortunately, although I can get individual countries, I cannot get results for the whole column yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`clean_country()`](https://docs.dataprep.ai/user_guide/clean/clean_country.html) from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/). Install it with `pip install dataprep`.

```py
from dataprep.clean import clean_country
df = pd.DataFrame({"address": ["Turin, Italy", np.nan, "Zurich, Switzerland", np.nan, "Glyfada, Greece"]})
df2 = clean_country(df, "address")
df2
               address address_clean
0         Turin, Italy         Italy
1                  NaN           NaN
2  Zurich, Switzerland   Switzerland
3                  NaN           NaN
4      Glyfada, Greece        Greece
```